# FileSystem.FileCopy vs objFSO.CopyFile

Tags: vba, excel

Are there specific scenarios where I should use on of the following or are they interchangeable?

Option 1

```
...
FileSystem.FileCopy...
...
```

Option 2

```
...    
Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.CopyFile
...
```

Or is option 1, under the hood, just option 2 ?

Comment: `FileSystem.FileCopy` seems to not take wildcards as opposed to `FSO.CopyFile` where you can copy a bunch of files at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1's `FileSystem.FileCopy` is the built-in VBA function to copy a file, its part of the core language and always available (you don't need the `FileSystem` namespace prefix)

Option 2 is more complex; it uses COM to create a late-bound FSO instance and calls a method that has the same name and does the same thing as the built-in.

There seems little benefit in using option 2 over option 1, the only functional  difference is that the FSO exposes an argument to control overwrite behaviour, something you would need to deal with manually using the built in `FileCopy` (trivial enough).

Comment: thanks Alex. I've implemented both in previous code just never really thought about differences. Is simpLE Man's comment valid?

Comment: Yes its a good observation, you cant use wildcards with the VBA function.  (Although you can achieve the same effect with other built-ins)

Comment: I've found that the FileCopy method can fail if the source file is open by another user but the FSO method works in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the FileCopy method can fail if the source file is open by another user but the FSO method works in both cases.

Comment: cheers M1chael - yes I pretty much always now use the FileSystemObject when doing this sort of work - like you say it seems safer

Answer (score 1):

I need to copy files with Chinese/Japanese characters to folders also with Chinese/Japanese characters, on a computer set to Chinese system locale.

I tried using FileCopy but encountered:

> runtime error 75 "Path/File access error"

when there isn't a backslash at the end of the destination filepath, and

> runtime error 76 "Path not found"

when I included the backslash.

However, it worked perfectly when I used CopyFile.
But note that the destination filepath needs to include backslash, otherwise will encounter runtime error 70 "Permission denied".

1. FileCopy with no backslash - runtime error 75 "Path/File access error"
2. FileCopy with backslash - runtime error 76 "Path not found"
3. CopyFile with no backslash - runtime error 70 "Permission denied"
4. CopyFile with backslash - OK
   .

Answer (score 1):

getting back with this thing. If it is helpful for anyone... I found, let´s say, a 3erd method by using "FSOobjet.Copy NewFilePath" which seems to be respecting the real 'DateCreated' property. The first two methods, at least in my case, they just inherit the original file's DateCreated property... which sometimes we do not want to; if we then want to make a filter, for example, depending the real date when these files were "created".
Regards.